# INSERT with alias name is not working on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.3

SQL Query on PostgreSQL:

```
insert into TOKEPOOLAMT (TOKEPOOLAMT.TOKEPOOLAMTID,TOKEPOOLAMT.TOKERULEID)
values (151, 176);
```

Giving error:

> ```
> com.edb.util.PSQLException:
> ERROR: column "tokepoolamt" of relation "tokepoolamt" does not exist
> ```

But:

```
insert into TOKEPOOLAMT (TOKEPOOLAMTID,TOKERULEID) values (151, 176);
```

is working fine.

Can anybody explain why alias name with column in insert statement not working?

Comment: Looks like an issue with UPPER and lower case object names. How did you create the table and it's columns? Advice: Only use lower case.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of case. I tried with both the cases. And first query is not working but second without alias is working.

Comment: `TOKEPOOLAMTID` is not an alias, that's your column's name. What you tried first is to qualify your column names with its table-name (which is more than a simple column name, but still not an *alias*), but that simply not necessary, in fact not supported at all.

Comment: ***column** The name of a column in the table named by table_name. The column name can be qualified with a subfield name or array subscript, if needed. (Inserting into only some fields of a composite column leaves the other fields null.)* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: @pozs : I do agree with your comments and it's also correct that postgresql doesn't support insert statement with TableName.ColumnName, because it does not found it qualified column name.

Answer (score 3):

There are no aliases involved here. Your error is that column names in the column list of an `INSERT` command cannot be table-qualified. @pozs already provided the fitting quote from the manual [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455023/insert-with-alias-name-is-not-working-on-postgresql/28455588#comment45237504_28455023).

> I don't think it's an issue of case. I tried with both the cases.

That's missing the point. In Postgres, identifiers are folded to lower case **unless double-quoted**. If you double-quoted a name at creation time you preserved a case sensitive spelling and need to double-quote for the rest of the object's life - unless it was a legal, lower-case name to begin with, then quoting won't make a difference. Details:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)